Is it reasonable to use background subtraction to identify some objects in sequential frame images to start labeling objects for YOLO training?
I know background subtraction is not a complete solution for object detection, but I’ve tried it for identifying potential new objects appearing in fixed background camera scenarios (millions of images to parse through for manual labeling). The idea was to use background subtraction to find at least an initial sample of more obvious objects in the raw data to start labeling for a training set (a sort of sample heuristic), and begin iterating on training the YOLO model so that later it can generalize and identify more subtle objects following fine-tuning. Is there anything wrong with that approach despite initial limitations? How would it compare to using simulated data to start out instead?
